# Two teams are going to play a best-of-7 match ....

Tags: probability

Two teams are going to play a best-of-7 match (the match will end as soon as either team has won 4 games). Each game ends in a win for a team and a loss for the other team. Assume that each game is equally likely to win each game, and that the games played are independent. Find the expectation and variance of the number of games being played.

- I started off with $P(X=k)$= 2$\binom{k-1}{3}/(2^k)$ = $\binom{k-1}{3}/(2^{k-1})$ as the main formula.
- Then using the formula, I got the expectation to be: E(x) = 4[$\binom{3}{3}/(2^3)]$ + 5[$\binom{4}{3}/(2^4)$] + 6[$\binom{5}{3}/(2^5)$] + 7[$\binom{6}{3}/(2^6)$] = 5.82125
- Using the Var(x) = E($x^2$) - $(E(x))^2$ formula I got:  Var(x) = 34.8125 - $(5.82125)^2$ = 1.027
- I am just unsure if my work is correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That looks reasonable, barring any arithmetic error.